# Selecting a specific <td> element inside a <tr> element and displaying text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two on change events that check for the inputted dates. If the date exceeds to the compared date, spits out an alert message. All this happens after a click away from the text box.

```
 //This on change event works perfectly fine

 $("td[date1] > input").on("change", function () {
                var cur_td = $(this).closest("tr");
                var startdate = $(this).val();
                var enddate = cur_td.find("td[date2]").text();
                var d1 = Date.parse(startdate);
                var d2 = Date.parse(enddate);
                if (d1 > d2) {
                    alert("The date exceeds End Date. Please check the date and re-enter it.");
                   }
            });

 // This on change event doesn't work... 

$("td[date2] > input").on("change", function () {
                    var cur = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var str = $(this).val();
                    var end = cur.find("td[date3]").text(); // Problem here
                    alert(end); // Returning blank.. 
                    var t1 = Date.parse(str);
                    var t2 = Date.parse(end);
                    if (t1 > t2) {
                       alert("The date exceeds End Date. Please check the date and re-enter it.");
                    }

                });
```

Razor View:

```
<td date1><input class="start" id=@item.ID type="text" actual="1" value='@(item.Date1 == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>

<td date2><input class="end" id=@item.ID type="text" actual="1" value='@(item.Date2== null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date2).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))' readonly="readonly" /></td>

<td date3>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date3)</td>
```

**Problem**

The first on change event works perfectly fine, however the second one is not doing the same thing.

```
 var end = cur_td.find("td[date3]").text();
 alert(end);
```

This is returning a blank. I don't understand how is it not able to find the `td` element. They're both the same exact functions comparing different dates.

Comment: You have a typo difference in second version between `curr` and `curr_td`

Comment: That's just a typo.. sorry about that.. the problem still exists.

Comment: Create a runnable html version that doen't include server side code so others can also run this

Comment: You also messed up with edit by removing the `find()` part of the chain

Comment: this `cur("td[date3]").text();`  should be `cur.find("td[date3]").text();`, `cur` its a jquery object, not function, you need to use `find()`

Comment: Thanks for that, just realized it... @charlietfl going to try your suggestion now

Comment: @JuanCastillo problem still remains

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure <td date3></td> contains content? Like is that `@Html.DisplayFor` actually rendering anything?

Comment: Yes, its coming from the database. @cody

Comment: I'll echo the need for the rendered HTML and a fully client-side example that displays the issue.  I see a couple of issues, to start.  Both inputs have the same ID (not valid HTML), you are handling the `change` event of `readonly` inputs, and there are a few more... stack-snippets are your friend.

Comment: I figured out the issue, `.text()` doesn't do justice because its an editable field. I had to add compare the dates based on its `input val`.